# Azure App Service cannot connect to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an API who uses entity framework to connect to a default database (Azure SQL). This API also connects to a number of different sources on Azure of which one is Azure SQL (different from the default connection).

This API is deployed to a worker app service under App Service Environement ressource in Azure and works perfectly.

It has connection string managed by entity framework defined as such in web.config:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:[SQLServer],1433;Initial Catalog=[DBName];User ID=[User];Password=[pwd]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

and other connections to Azure SQL databases managed manually like this:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="LiveDB" value="Server=[SQLServer];Database=[DBName];User Id=[User];Password=[pwd]" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Now for some reason I'm trying to publish this API to a new API App Service and this ressource cannot connect to the later Azure SQL data source (LiveDB). This was not a problem under the App Serve Environment.

Anyone knows why this would be an issue?

I think i've really isolated the problem to connection string.

Comment: Why do two connection string have different format? The second one doesn't really look like Azure SQL connection. Also why store connection string in `appSettings`, not `connectionStrings`?

Comment: Now that you mention it I'm wondering that. I don't have access to the person who coded this and it's not precisely documented. This question has the ring of an answer. I'll work on this and update.

Comment: It seems the problem was with Firewall settings on an on premise SQL Server. Connection string format did not play a role.